# 421 Misdirected Request on Shared Host

Tags: apache, https

I am on a shared host (Apache) and am receiving little help resolving this issue. I have a main domain https://www.waldorfteacherresources.com and I have set up two cookieless domains: static.waldorfteacherresources.com and static.mseifert.com. When loading, Firefox shows many of the static files with a 421 response. Occasionally, the main site's index.php comes back with a 421 error - which then gets displayed in the browser directly.  Each time when loading a url, the files with 421 errors can vary. Sometimes I get no 421 responses.

Also odd is that even with files having a 421 response, they seem to load anyway: the `css` files are getting loaded (otherwise the site would not render correctly) and the `javascript` files appear in the debug tab of Firefox.

I am using Comodo SSL and have PositiveSSL Multi-Domain Certificate. The response I get from my ISP is

> After reviewing this it looks like the main issue is your sites code
>   is working in a way that is confusing the server.
>
> It appears for some reason the site is making a request to itself and
>   presenting the host header as www.waldorfteacherresources.com while it
>   is actually going to static.waldorfteacherresources.com.

I have read the discussion on [421 Errors here](https://serverfault.com/questions/772901/421-misdirected-request-using-http-2-and-san-ssl#773282) but this isn't helping me figure out if it is somehow my code creating the problem or if there is something on the ISP end that can be changed (of if I need to find a new ISP). Since it is a shared host, they are not going to change the server configuration.

Below are Firefox's network tab for two loads of the same URL. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Fresh load of url]

[image: Second load of url]

**UPDATE** Ok, almost a couple of years later and decided it was time to deal with it. I was able to get most of the problems resolved by removing my static domains which served images and javascript. However, I was still using a second domain for some of this content and Safari in particular was still giving me problems.

I set about getting separate certificates for each domain. I am on a shared host (Webhostinghub) and discovered they now offer free SSL (AutoSSL) that auto renews. It sounded to good to be true. They set me up with 6 free certificates. So far so good. I may even try to re-enable the static domains to test. If this all works, I'll save $ to boot as a bonus and let my Comodo certificates expire in July.

Comment: This is specific to HTTP/2 and TLS. As the last of your link shows, it depends on how each VirtualHost is configured inside Apache. You are exactly in this case because you have a single certificate with all related names as SANs.

Comment: "Also odd is that even with files having a 421 response, they seem to load anyway" as specified by RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-9.1.2 : "Clients receiving a 421 (Misdirected Request) response from a server
   MAY retry the request -- whether the request method is idempotent or
   not -- over a different connection.  This is possible if a connection
   is reused (Section 9.1.1) or if an alternative service is selected
   [ALT-SVC]."

Comment: Can the ISP install 2 separate certificates, one for each name? If so, you may try that instead of a certificate with SANs.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I will look into this. Since I bought from Comodo, my guess would be that I need to purchase something different. Not sure what individual certificates are called. Since I have six certificates total (for my 3 sites), this could get very expensive.

Comment: Let's Encrypt certificates are free. You should also give the link you posted here about the answer on these errors to your hoster as it clearly shows the problem is with the Apache configuration, and you do not control it...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The problem with Let's Encrypt certificates is the short 90 day duration before they expire. I don't think I can set up auto renew on a shared host.

Comment: It is not described as a problem but a feature :-) Note that it could be even lower. Maybe it is more complicated indeed on share hosting. But you have also the DNS validation, if you control your DNS hosting. However even with that you need later to install the new certificate on your web hoster. So indeed it could make your like  more complicated but at least you could first try with that, before spending money, to see if it solves your problem, as other options seem to be having your webhoster change its configuration, or for you to change webhosting company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

421 is returned when the browser tries to reuse the connection for another site. This is allowed under HTTP/2 to save the cost of opening another connection as, in most cases, it is better to use fewer connections under HTTP/2.

The browser should only reuse a connection which maps to the same IP address and where the certificate used covers both sites (which is the case for your three sites).

Despite these conditions, occasionally the browser will try to reuse a connection when it shouldn’t. The main case for Apache is if different SSL/TLS settings are set up for each vhost. Looking at ssllabs.com for each of your three domains there setup looks the same so finding it difficult to see why Apache is returning this. You should get in touch with your hosting providing and ask them to verify this.

In these cases Firefox will see the 421 response, establish a new connection and request the resource again. Though, unlike a 301or 302 it looks like this will not show as a separate request in developer tools.

The alternatives to fix this are:

1. Get the hosting provider to identify the cause and allow the connections to be reused.
2. Use different certs for each domain (so the browser won’t try to reuse the connection).
3. Use different IP address for the other domains even if they map to the same server (so the browser won’t try to reuse the connection).
4. Stop using http/2 - which seems a shame since it’s usually gives a good performance gain.
5. Stop using other domains, at least for HTTP/2.

I think you should seriously look at the last one. The benefit of using other domains (called sharding) is often overstated in my opinion for HTTP/1 and should not be necessary under HTTP/2.

Sharding is done for two reasons:

1. To allow 6 more connections under HTTP/1.1 as browsers typical max out at 6 simultaneous connections per domain. However, unless those 7th, 8th...etc connections are used a lot the cost of setting them up may not be worthwhile. And under HTTP/2 the limit is much higher (usually at least simultaneous 100 streams per connection).
2. Cookie-less domains to save on request sizes. But under HTTP/2, HTTP headers are compressed so you are less worried about this (and again in my opinion the value of this was overstated - how big are cookies really.).

Looking at [webpagetest for your homepage](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180904_BA_105e06c517dabb8a71b3c8d760f45c1c/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1), you are loading the main page over the www domain, and then 6 assets over one static sub domain and 6 assets over the next subdomain and the a few more over each:

[image: Waterfall view]

Here you can see the true cost of your 421s as nearly every connection has to be restablished with a connect and SSL negotiation. Ignoring this for a bit you can see that, yes iyou are downloading more than 6 resources at the same time over your two static subdomains. So if this was an HTTP/1.1 connection you would benefit from breaking the 6 connection limit for a bit. But you are also wasting the www connection which is idle after the first request. This is made more obvious from the Connection View:

[image: Connection View]

So you could get rid of one of those subdomains and serve those assets for the www domain to getting utilization out of that first connection.

For HTTP/2 you can get rid of the other domain too as shouldn’t be needed. You can then either serve different results to HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1 users but that is complicated, [all the main browsers support HTTP/2](https://caniuse.com/#feat=http2) and for 24 requests in total it’s not even going to be much of a performance drag going to one domain for those that don’t.

In summary stop sharding to cookieless domains unless you have a real good reason to, as from a quick look at your home page anyway, it is not helping your performance and while you are hitting this 421 issue you are hindering it considerably.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and time spent looking into it. The Home Page is not a good representation. I can serve a lot of images on a page - sometimes easily over 100 e.g. https://www.waldorfteacherresources.com/index.php?topid=1&grade=4&page=FormDrawing  At what point is it a "good reason"?

Comment: Precisely what HTTP/2 is good at - without needing extra domains and connections! I’m fact, because of this. Firefox tries to automatically unshard for you when using HTTP/2, which is where you see you issue!

Comment: Also looking at that page you are serving all the images off of one domain anyway so benefit very little from sharding even under HTTP/1.1: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180904_AW_8b2bf160140ed0406f40de43651dd12c/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

Comment: Funny I haven't read any of this with everyone advising for cookieless domains. Maybe that's old content. Seems I will have to go back to just using the one domain as you advise. Seems a shame after all the reading and configuring of code. I am not familiar with the term "sharding" so I'll look into it more. I may try getting Comodo to issue separate certificates for the domains instead of a multi-domain certificate to see if it has any impact. They have a free 30 day  return policy and at least I'll know if there is a solution before I go through the effort of re-coding the site. Thanks again

Comment: HTTP/2 changes a lot of things. You may be interested in my post here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/why-do-we-need-http2/. And if that does interest you, then also the book it was an except from :-)

Comment: Since I store all domain references in a single included file, I decided to quickly test out removing the static domains. Unfortunately, I still have two domains I need to pull from. Not all my files can be pulled from the site's domain (the site referenced above is a sub domain of my root site). So some of the files still are pulled from a level up and there is no fix for this. It obviously reduces the number of 421 errors but not completely. I still need to find a better solution.

Comment: I've always thought that cookie-less domains help (browser) caching? Maybe this is mostly historical as I can can't find much about it these days (except for [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/47053/52912) on another Webmasters question). The very act of sending the cookie was enough to prevent the resource being cache?

Comment: Nope! Look at any website that uses cookies and you'll see lots of resources being cached even when cookies are set. Now if a resource is protected (e.g. your online banking summary screen) then you won't be able to access it without cookies and the application will usually explicitly set such a resource to be non-cachable. But that doesn't happen automatically by the browser based on cookies being there or not.